# Error while doing module.exports = client;

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, discord.js, client

I have a commands folder containing files that contains slash commands, and i have to import the client instance from index.js to another file, but when doing :

`module.exports = client;`

it execute the entire index.js script ! I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried to make the instance in another file than index.js and then import the instance in index, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean it's executing your index.js script? Could you share your code in index.js?

Answer (score 0):

At least from what I'm understanding, (assuming you already had registered the commands and had a client object set up) you could pass client through into `command.execute()` as an argument (on the 10th line in the snippet):

in index.js:

```js
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
  const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
  if (!command) {
    console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
    return;
  }
  try {
    console.log(`running command "${interaction.commandName}"!`);
    await command.execute(interaction,client);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
  }
});
```

And then take that argument within the command's module:

In `commands/yourcommand.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  //[...] other slash command setup bits and bobs

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

[modified version of discordjs guide snippets](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#executing-commands)

Feel free to ask if there's any need for elaboration or clarification; hope this helps & cheers!

Comment: thx bro, now it could work, i just get the error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels') but i'll try to figure out by myself

Answer (score 0):

Most objects in discord.js have access to the client, using simply `.client`. Notice the [`Base`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Base?scrollTo=client) class has a `.client` property, and all interactions extend [`BaseInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseInteraction?scrollTo=client), which extends `Base`. This means using `interaction.client` will give you access to the client.

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  const client = interaction.client
}
```